# Помогите создать двумерный список

Tags: c++, списки, std-list

Не получается создать двумерный список( Одномерный понятно как создавать, а вот с двумерным беда.

Что написал:

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;

struct G{
    G*k;
};
list<list<G>> *n;

void main() {
    n = new list<list<G>>();// Это вроде верно
    n.push_back(new G());// а тут как быть?
// n[0]. ... тоже не работает(
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых не надо создавать `std::list` c помощью `new`. Этот тип имеет семантику значения, как и `int`, и его надо использовать так же.

Во-вторых, Вам надо создать хотя бы один вложенный  список, перед тем как класть туда `G()`.

```
list<list<G>> n;
n.push_back(list<G>()); // положили новый список в список верхнего уровня
n.back().push_back(G());
```

Либо, можно использовать инициализатор

```
list<list<G>> n = {{G()}}; // список а в нем список с одним G
```

или `emplace_back`

```
list<list<G>> n;
n.emplace_back({G()}); // добавляем список из одного G
```

Comment: Список хранит не указатели, стоит поправить.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вы хотите использовать стандартный класс std::list для хранения вашего собственного списка, элемент которого определяется структурой

```
struct G{
    G*k;
};
```

Для этого достаточно в main, которая должна быть объявлена как

```
int main()
```

включить объявление

```
std::list<G *> l;
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы этот список уже содержал пустой список типа `G`, то вы можете написать

```
l.push_back( nullptr );
```

У стандартного списка нет оператора индексации. Поэтому вы можете обращаться к первому элементу общего списка с помощью метода `front`

Например,

```
l.push_back( nullptr );

l.front = new G { nullptr };
```

Либо использовать итераторы и общие функции `std::next`, `std::prev` для позиционирования итератора на конкретный элемент общего списка.